# Need to copy missing files from one server subdirectory to another sub directory of same file and folder name

Tags: powershell

I want to compare files from two paths which have the same folder and file name and copy the missing file from one subdirectory to the other subdirectory.

Eg two server like "Production" and "DR" server both servers share a folder, sub folder and file name.

What I need, is to compare and check for missing files and copy the missing files from "Prodution" to "DR".

I have tried the following code but it is copying data outside subfolder.

```
$Folder1Path = 'C:\Users\valayakaranaig\Desktop\BMS\'
$Folder2Path = 'U:\BMS\'

$Folder1Files = get-childitem -Path $Folder1Path -recurse
$Folder2Files = get-childitem -Path $Folder2Path -recurse

$FileDiffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1Files -DifferenceObject $Folder2Files

$FileDiffs.InputObject.FullName

 foreach ($files in $FileDiffs.InputObject.Fullname) 
{

Copy-Item -Path $files -Destination $Folder2Path -Recurse -Force

}
```

Comment: the robocopy utility can be called from inside PoSh ... and robocopy is _far, far, FAR_ faster than any native powershell code will be. plus, it is specifically designed for what you appear to want to do ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the server which i need to copy is 2003 server. i believe robocopy will not work on this server.

Comment: while robocopy has been bundled with very version of windows for quite some time, for 2003 it is part of the resource kit. if you cannot install it on that server, then download the resource kit, extract the file, and copy that to the target system. ///// if you are not allowed to do that ... then how did you get powershell on that system? [*grin*]